# Cannot represent non-enum value

Tags: typescript, enums, graphql, typegraphql

In my graphQL API(with typescript & type-graphql) I'm trying to run a mutation which ***inputType*** has an ***enum*** value defined as below

```
export enum GenderType {
  female = 'female',
  male = 'male',
}

registerEnumType(GenderType, {
  name: 'GenderType',
});
```

and I'm trying to execute this mutation.

```
mutation {
  registerStudent(data: {
    name: "John",
    gender: "male",
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

but when I'm trying to execute the mutation it gives an error saying

> **"message": "Enum "GenderType" cannot represent non-enum value: "female". Did you mean the enum value "female" or "male"?"**,

I think this happens because how i defined the enum type using registerEnumType in ***type-graphql***.

How to defile an [enum with type-graphql](https://typegraphql.com/docs/enums.html)

Comment: Found the problem... Actually problem located at mutation object types that i passed. First i passed  gender: "male" but it's an enum so it has own values. then i tried as gender: male 

It worked. just pass it as male without "male" ⚡

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted. That way you'll be helping anyone else with the same problem and clearly indicating that there is an answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah this was confusing AF

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found the problem...

Actually problem located at mutation object data that I passed.

First I pass gender type as a ***String*** that cause the problem.

```
mutation {
  registerStudent(data: {
    name: "John",
    gender: "male",
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

This is wrong bcz It's a String, Program is expecting a value we defined in enums so pass enum values as it is.

```
mutation {
  registerStudent(data: {
    name: "John",
    gender: male,
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```